# How to make a button transparent for mouse click but not for hover?

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to make a `QPushButton` transparent to clicks but still visible to hover events?

While searching about I found this flag:

```
button->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);
```

But the widget doesn't obey the CSS set on `QPushButton::hover`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass QPushButton and override mousePressEvent.

```
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QMouseEvent>

class Button : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Button() {}
    ~Button() {}

private:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event) override
    {
        event->ignore();
    }
};
```